# How to calculate avg of a value?

Tags: logic, education, average

I need to calculate the average of the games that ended with at least two goals (`ov 1.5`), more than two goals (`ov 2.5`) and with more than three goals (`ov 3.5`).

I start based on these historical data:

Matches ended in Over:     `1.5 | 2.5 | 3.5`
                                                                      `22  |  13 |  5`

Matches endend in Under:  `1.5 | 2.5 | 3.5`
                                                                         `4  |  13 |  21`

as you can see we have two types of matches:

- Over: indicates the matches ended with more than x goals
- Under: indicates the matches ended with less than x goals

For evaluate for example the average of `Ov 2.5` (all the matches ended with at least three goals), I wrote this formula: `(13 / (4 + 22))*100`.

Basically `13` is the number of matches ended with two goals `ov 2.5`, meanwhile `4` is the number of matches ended with 1 goal, and `22` is the number of matches ended with at least 2 goals `ov 1.5`.

```
(13 / (4 + 22))*100 = 50%
```

I have this question:
Is my logic good?

Can I improve this?

How can I calculate also the `under` average and the `over 1.5`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As a comment (I can't write those yet): The use of the word "average" here is a bit misleading (I thought you mean, average number of goals in games where there were over 2.5 goals etc.) You want to calculate the proportion or percentage of the games, that ended in a given category?

So, for example, in case of "over 2.5" your thinking is correct, it's the number of the games you're interested in - $13$ for "over 2.5", divided by the *total* number of games, which you can find adding any two "over $X$" and "under $X$" (for X not being an integer of course) - you chose $X=1.5$. The result is correct.